# Run java script events while page is loading in browser

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have one text box on my web page, I have written logic on text change event in java script. but this event is only work when page is loaded completely. while page is loading in browser this event is not firing.

I have number of images on my web page so page is taking time to load. but text box is displaying at staring and images are taking time to load.

while page is loading in browser other events of java script (like button click event) are also not working. is there a way to work these events while page is loading in browser?

My Project is in AngularJS.

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: When number of images is there in your page and if it is creating problem then you can use Jquery plugin like [LazyLoading](https://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload)

Answer (score 0):

Load the page as soon as possible with blank images, then use AJAX calls (or angular directives in your case probably) to load the images async afterward?? Alternatively you can try putting your javascript higher up in the page... but this is not generally a good idea so I would try first way.